# How to convert a memory address into a char string

Tags: c

I want to convert an address of a memory segement into char string.

Here is an example of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int size = 20;
    char buffer[10];
    char *ptr = (char*) malloc(size);
    printf("Ptr addr: %p\n", ptr);
    if(ptr != NULL)
    {
        snprintf(buffer, "%p", ptr);
        printf("Ptr addr stored in buffer: %p\n", buffer);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**output:**

Ptr addr: 0x55ab2a43e260

Ptr addr stored in buffer: 0x7ffe9a76470e

Unfortunatelly, I have two different addresses when I use the approach from my example code. 
Can please someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Best regards,
Usam

Comment: You should get errors as you call `snprintf` with the wrong (and to few) arguments. Please make sure that the [mcve] you show don't contain any unrelated errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code prints the **address** of `buffer`, not what's in it:

```
printf("Ptr addr stored in buffer: %p\n", buffer);
```

You probably want

```
printf("Ptr addr stored in buffer: %s\n", buffer);
```

given that the previous code populated `buffer` with the string representation of the **contents** of `ptr`.

And as noted in the comments, your call to `snprintf()` isn't correct.  It should be

```
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%p", (void *) ptr);
```

Note the cast to `(void *)` - the `%p` format specifier requires a `void *` pointer.

`buffer` might also need to be longer than 10 bytes, depending on your system.

Comment: You have addressed only one of (at least) two errors in OP's code. Look at the `snprintf` call!

Answer (score 3):

Two errors in your code

1) Wrong snprint - you missed the 2nd parameter which is the size of the buffer.

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%p", ptr);
```

2) Wrong format to print the buffer - it should be %s for string

```
printf("Ptr addr stored in buffer: %s\n", buffer);
```